# Basic Cycles memory usage @98%?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, memory-management

I have a scene that sometimes crashes for CUDA errors (out of memory). So I put all elements on separate layers to figure out in rendered view which was the culprit. 
Turns out, even if I have only the HDRI world background on, or even if I switch to an empty layer AND disconnect the world output node, I'm still at a usage of almost all my VRam. The umber doesn't really change at all.
Also, switching to a primitive 8bit image doesn't make a change.
In essence: verything on: 98%, everything off 98%.
What am I not getting here? Still new to Cycles, sorry :(

Comment: Is it, that Cycles stores all data in VRam permanently?

Comment: Hard to tell from description alone. Blender probably just loads the whole scene into memory and keeps it there to avoid the trouble of resending everything into GPU again. Also VRAM is not exclusively used by cycles. Blender itself also uses it, so does displaying the scene on viewport, and the OS will also take its toll.

Comment: That's what I assumed, that EVERYTHING gets loaded into VRAM. At least it's the only thing that makes sense. I have a GPU tool running to see what changes. I'll try to deactivate some in the outliner,  maybe that will clarify things.